# Ghost API Endpoint still existing after deletion, redploying, clearing cache, and reinstalling Tomee

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jax-rs, apache-tomee

Calling it Ghost API because no idea how this endpoint is still running.

Details of how this issue arose:

2 identical POST endpoints:
endPoint1
endPoint2 <-- Will not work whatsoever, identical to Endpoint1, only difference is the name.

```
    @POST // 
    @Path ("endPoint2")
    public Response postEndPoint2( String requestData)
    {
        Response returnStatus;
        try
        {
            
            //Code to shoot over message to ZMQ (ZeroMQ)
            System.out.println(returnStatus);
            
        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println ( "Error sending " + e.getMessage());
            returnStatus = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
        return returnStatus;
    }
```

endPoint1 and endpoint2 are absolutely identical, other than the @Path name being different and the method name

endPoint1 works, endPoint2 does not.

I deleted endPoint2, renamed endPoint1 to 'endPoint2'. Still, it will not work.

What is now weirder, endPoint1 is still accepting data?????

It has been deleted, heck, even deleted the entire file, and the endpoint is still processing data

I know it is processing data because after getting a request, the API would carry the data across a message broker (ZMQ), and it is still receiving messages.

Apache Tomee
NetBeans
and JavaX.ws.rs is the stack

Anyone run into anything similar?

I have reinstalled apache tomee, commented the entire file out that has the endpoints, endpoint is a 'ghost' and is still being recieved somehow. Delted WAR files and redeployed them by hand.

Comment: Do you have another binaries API version jar in the app also? do you have a collective jar that also contains ghost API in it among other API's as a supplement? , Does TomEE contain ghost API in its binaries?   It will overwrite in the app on loading in order of copy loading, or if part of TomEE will remain until configured out.